# Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that once I click a certain button in my extension, it will highlight the current tab. However, I am having a little bit of trouble.

Right now I have
`document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {}` in my JS file, but I can't seem to find a solution on how to colour the current tab. I know something is supposed to go in {}, but I am not exactly sure what. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, there are no methods or properties available as part of the [`tabs` API for Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs) that allow you to set/modify the color of a tab.

<del>Thus, this is not (currently) possible to accomplish from within the extension context within Chrome.</del>

**EDIT**: On second thought, this actually *might* be possible, albeit in a bit of a shoehorned manner. By adding [the example function to get the current tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#get-the-current-tab) (and then its `id` property), you can pass it to the [`chrome.tabs.group()` method](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-group), then access the returned `tabGroup` in the `callback` parameter to set its [`color` property](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabGroups/#type-Color):

```
chrome.tabs.group(
    options: {
        tabIds: (await getCurrentTab()).id
    },
    callback: function(groupId) {
        chrome.tabGroups.update(
            groupId: groupId,
            updateProperties: {
                color: "red"
            }
        );
    }
);
```

However, it's not clear if the resulting visual meets your requirements or not.